# 'folly/Portability.h' file not found React library

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Running into a build failure on Xcode with my react native project.
the error is `'folly/Portability.h' file not found`

I have been trying to fix this issue on my own for the last few days but unable resolve it.

RN info:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz
      Memory: 641.79 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.8 => 0.59.8 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Required by RNFirebase
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20.1'

target 'WhosThat_app' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.7.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.1'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.1'
  # Pods for WhosThat_app
  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'
  pod 'RNBackgroundGeolocation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation'
  pod 'RNBackgroundFetch', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch'
  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'Folly', podspec: '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'WhosThat_app-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing


  end

  target 'WhosThat_appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Tried removing the pods folder and reinstalling them and removing node-modules folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your `Podfile` inside `target 'WhosThat_app' do`:

```
target 'WhosThat_app' do

  # ...everything else

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'React'
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
```

I didn't need the following line and believe you can remove it:

```
pod 'Folly', podspec: '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

**Notes**:

- Solution works for React Native version `59`.
- [Found the solution here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24192#issuecomment-479500780) and tested that it worked.

Comment: Hi @Andru
I tried your suggestion and when I run 'pod install' I am getting the following error: '[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting then or ';' or '\n'
      en...get.remove_from_project'
---- Any idea?

Comment: @Yossi No idea. Looks like you should check the syntax. Have you perhaps forgotten some comma or something?

Comment: Typed again the whole podfile, and the error is gone, although the text seems identical. Not sure what was the problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue you should make two things:

1) Add **CxxBridge** subspec

2) Point **DoubleConversion** and **glog** dependencies specs directly for **Folly**

Podfile sample:

```
# React Native
rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTLinkingIOS'
]
pod 'yoga', :path => "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
  'ART',
  'Core',
  'CxxBridge',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTLinkingIOS',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTAnimation',
  'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
  'RCTActionSheet',
  'RCTGeolocation',
  'RCTSettings',
  'RCTVibration',
  'DevSupport',
  'RCTPushNotification'
]
```

by adding these my problem is resolved successfully.