# React Native fatal error: 'folly/Portability.h' file not found on XCode 12.5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cross-platform, signal-protocol

When i try to run the code, it is giving an error as follows from SignalProtocolC.

> In file included from /Users/tsuser/Desktop/user/MyProject/MyProject-MOBILE/ios/Pods/SignalProtocolC/src/curve25519/ed25519/tests/internal_slow_tests.c:10:
> /Users/tsuser/Desktop/user/MyProject/MyProject-MOBILE/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/Utility.h:19:10: fatal error: 'folly/Portability.h' file not found

This was working properly before the xcode update. I have looked other similar questions in stack overflow. but all are giving solutions for older versions which are not working for issue in xcode 12.5.1. One of the answer I tried is in following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57709111/10722603